# To find the font name ? Closest match?

Tags: css, fonts

I want to find out following font name, or something closely matching this format. I just wonder how do i do it ? since googling it wont do any help. Any designer resource or instructions on how to archive this ?

Font i am after is

[image]

Comment: [This](https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) link, for example. SO is for questions about programming. I'm really feel myself strange and confused when tell such things to users, who have a much more score then mine :-) Also googling - "find font by image" - or something like this. Or, [graphic design](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/) at StackExchange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't encourage these types of questions, but I will try and help anyway.

Using [WhatTheFont](https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/), You can look through an array of all [these](https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/results?ch%5B0%5D=B&ch%5B1%5D=R&ch%5B2%5D=I&ch%5B3%5D=L&ch%5B4%5D=N&ch%5B5%5D=K&ch%5B6%5D=N&session=0019bd3c56844c61000af9df000032e00&x=41&y=45) fonts and decide why one is perfect for you.

Comment: I see that the search session expired, you can just upload your picture to the site and get the same results, good luck.